# Java getAudioInputStream() Symbol not found

Tags: java

I have created a `class` to play the sound when I click the buttons.

Here is the code :

```
public void playSound()
    {
        try 
        {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("beep-1.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip( );
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start( );
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }
```

But when I compile, I get this error :

```
error: cannot find symbol
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("beep-1.wav"));
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class File
  location: class MemoryGame
1 error

Process completed.
```

What is the problem with the `getAudioInputStream()`?

I had used `import javax.sound.sampled.*;` in my program.

Comment: Oops. I didn't import `io`. Sorry for my fault. By the way, when I want to play this sound, I use `playSound()` in the `ButtonListener`, but it doesn't play the sound. What wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to import `java.io.File`? That's the class the compiler says it doesn't know about.

Comment: My fault. Didn't import the `java.io.*`.